# display the modal relative to the user position on the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog

I am have an extending html page, the user can access the modal from the very bottom of the page but my problem is that the modal is always displayed on the top(sometime even not visible). I am using jquery for my modal not bootstrap, and this is how i am showing my modal:

```
    var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    $('#imagemodal').fadeIn($(this).data());
```

is there a way to make it relative to the user position on the page?

Comment: Assuming this is part of a callback, you can use the Event element for that callback to capture the X and Y position of the mouse and use it for positioning. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried `position:fixed;` on the modal wrapper, will assume its for `#imagemodal`, this will fix the element based on the "viewport/display" vs the page.

Comment: Thank you both, both of your answers helped me